Test Class Passes, but Should Fail
I have code that is supposed to share a custom object record with a Customer Community Plus user when that user is created. This should happen in the after insert user trigger.
Without using a future method, this should fail, and if I deploy the code and create the user, I can verify that it does fail throwing

MIXED_DML_OPERATION: DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): Client__Share, original object: User

...and no share records get created.
So why does this test pass?

Why does it pass when I use System.runAs() even without using an async method?

Shouldn't the mixed DML exception be thrown here regardless of context?


Why does it fail (due to mixed DML) when I use an async method to create the share record, but I exclude the System.runAs() call?
Using the async method actually succeeds in prod, it's just the test that fails.

@IsTest
static void shareClientOnCreatingPortalUser() {
    Client__c client = TestFactory.createClient();

    Account account = TestFactory.draftPersonAccount();
    account.Client__c = client.Id;
    insert account;

    Contact contact = [
        SELECT Account.Client__c
        FROM Contact
        WHERE AccountId = :account.Id
    ];

    UserRole role = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE PortalType = 'CustomerPortal' LIMIT 1];

    String nowMs = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().getTime());
    User portalUser = new User(
        ProfileId = CUSTOMER_COMMUNITY_PLUS_PROFILE_ID,
        LastName = nowMs,
        Username = nowMs + '@example.com',
        Email = nowMs + '@example.com',
        Alias = nowMs.left(8),
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
        ContactId = contact.Id,
        UserRoleId = role.Id
    );

    System.runAs( new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId()) ) {
        Test.startTest();
        insert portalUser;
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    List<Client__Share> shares = [
        SELECT ParentId, UserOrGroupId, AccessLevel, RowCause
        FROM Client__Share
    ];
    Assert.areEqual(1, shares.size());
    Assert.areEqual(portalUser.Id, shares[0].UserOrGroupId);
    Assert.areEqual(client.Id, shares[0].ParentId);
    Assert.areEqual('Read', shares[0].AccessLevel);
    Assert.areEqual('Manual', shares[0].RowCause);
}

For added reference, here is a very simplified version of what the trigger is doing. (The actual code runs in a trigger handler, is bulkified, etc.)
trigger UserTrigger on User (after insert) {
    User user = [SELECT Account.Client__c FROM User WHERE Id = :Trigger.New[0].Id];

    insert new Client__Share(
        ParentId = user.Account.Client__c,
        UserOrGroupId = user.Id,
        AccessLevel = 'Read',
        RowCause = 'Manual'
    );
}


Test.startTest(); runs as separate transaction. Move it to the test method's beginning and the MIXED_DML_OPERATION should appear.

@MariiaIllarionova Thank you for the idea. I think Test.startTest() just resets the governor limits–it doesn't create a new transaction. Regardless, I checked and the placement/existence of it makes no difference.

@Diego: MIXED_DML_OPERATION occurs only when specific field on user are set like UserRoleId etc. Please check this answer.

@Rohit Thank you, that lead somewhere. Explicitly adding the UserRoleId did throw the error. However, switching to a future method did not resolve it. In fact, reverting to synchronous execution and using System.runAs() (as shown in the updated question), the test continues to pass.

@Diego: Strange, the best way would be to raise a case with Salesforce and directly hear from horse's mouth. If you do raise a case, please update here with the findings.

@Rohit I think I figured it out. See my answer below.

Great . Upvoted.

When creating a user via the UI, the UserRoleId is set explicitly. This causes a mixed DML operation. However, specifying the UserRoleId was not necessary, in my case, because the user role was inferred from the running user and set at a lower level without context of mixed DML.
(Without using any future methods, I was able to successfully create the Client, Account, Contact, and User via anonymous apex. The UserRoleId was automatically populated and the share records were inserted.)
So, although it's not necessary, to most accurately test the experience of creating a user via the UI, we'll explicitly set the UserRoleId.
Now, why does the code fail when I use a future method without System.runAs()?
I think this comes down to two things:

Test.stopTest() will synchronously run all asynchronous processes that were called after Test.stopTest(). Notably, nothing is stated about being run in a different context or transaction, so these processes could still result in mixed DML.

"System.runAs() allows mixed DML..." Multiple people indicated this, but because I had my own misguided ideas about how this method worked, I found the official documentation to be insufficiently explicit:



You can also use the runAs method to perform mixed DML operations in your test by enclosing the DML operations within the runAs block.

For some reason, I thought this functioned by treating the runAs block as a separate transaction, which caused my confusion. Then I found a very clear comment in a bit of Salesforce's sample code:

// System.runAs() allows mixed DML operations in test context

In conclusion, the only way to "dismiss" the mixed DML error is to follow the instructions and wrap the DML in System.runAs.

@IsTest
static void shareClientOnCreatingPortalUser() {
    Client__c client = TestFactory.createClient();

    Account account = TestFactory.draftPersonAccount();
    account.Client__c = client.Id;
    insert account;

    Contact contact = [
        SELECT Account.Client__c
        FROM Contact
        WHERE AccountId = :account.Id
    ];

    User portalUser = TestFactory.draftPortalUser(contact.Id);

    System.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId())) {
        Test.startTest();
        insert portalUser;
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    List<Client__Share> shares = [
        SELECT ParentId, UserOrGroupId, AccessLevel, RowCause
        FROM Client__Share
    ];
    Assert.areEqual(1, shares.size());
    Assert.areEqual(portalUser.Id, shares[0].UserOrGroupId);
    Assert.areEqual(client.Id, shares[0].ParentId);
    Assert.areEqual('Read', shares[0].AccessLevel);
    Assert.areEqual('Manual', shares[0].RowCause);
}

The test passes due to the relaxed constraints in the test execution environment, which allows mixed DML operations that would normally fail in production. To ensure your code behaves correctly in a real-world scenario, handle mixed DML operations using future methods, queueable Apex, or System.runAs() for proper context switching.

Maybe I'm missing something, but my understanding was that System.runAs() would allow performing mixed DML operations by executing in a separate context. However, within that context, you could still get a DML exception. Is that incorrect? Is there any documentation that explicitly describes this? The official docs do not explicitly state that the constraints are relaxed.
